# mysql trigger after query with join

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I want to create a trigger that set new org_id when status changes to 'stock'.
I have 2 tables: functionalci that has attribute org_id and physicaldevice that has status.
The update that invokes the trigger is like:

```
UPDATE functionalci f
  JOIN physicaldevice d
    ON f.id = d.id
   SET d.status = 'stock', f.name ="XXX"  
 WHERE d.id = 2
```

When I try a trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER UPDATE ON physicaldevice 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN 
    UPDATE functionalci SET org_id=2  WHERE functionalci.id = OLD.id;
END;
```

I have this error: mysql_errno = 1442, mysql_error = Can't update table 'functionalci' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Is there any way to do the trigger without changing the UPDATE that invokes it?

Comment: A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger. You try to alter another table updated in this query - sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I will create some mysql events to solve the problem. Something like:

```
CREATE EVENT ev 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
    UPDATE functionalci f
    JOIN physicaldevice d
    ON f.id = d.id
    SET f.org_id = 2
    WHERE f.org_id <> 2 AND d.status LIKE "stock"
```

It's not the same as a trigger, but it works for me.